# Как сделать, чтобы фоновое изображение изменялось в зависимости от устройства?

Tags: html, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Есть сайт: `alicegoes.com` - сделан мной с помощью приложения [Mobirise](http://mobirise.com), которое использует bootstrap. Прога удобная, результат качественный, но функционал ограничен. Для первой итерации - самое оно, а дальше ручками по мелочи. Например, подцепил гугл-шрифты, заменил плавающий в параллаксе текст на картинку с лого, перенес иконки соц.сетей в шапку сайта из блока в теле и т.п.

На сайте самый верхний блок (сейчас афиша) при просмотре с ПК отображается как надо. Но вот **при просмотре со смартфона - отображается только середина фонового изображения**, видимо потому что задано заполнение картинкой во всю высоту экрана. Соответственно, это меня не устраивает.

Так оторажается с компа:
[image: на ПК]

Так отображается с телефона (прошу прощения за масштаб, хз как уменьшить):
[image: так отображается с телефона]

Вариантов решения проблемы вижу два:

1) с помощью атрибутов media и/или source выбирать какая картинка будет отображается на устройстве в зависимости от его типа
2) перезадать условие заполнения верхнего блока - не по высоте, а по ширине (не смог найти где это задано).

Первый вариант желаннее, но похоже, что без полного перетряхивания кода это не сделать, потому что картинка выбирается в атрибуте background, в который вроде как нельзя указать какой-то выбор (в отличие от picture), а при использовании picture картинка выбирается, но отображение сайта на смартфоне становится некорректным.

Еще есть мысль сделать свой section с параллаксом самому, с нуля... Но я вообще мало чего во всем этом понимаю и по сути могу только "накликать сайт мышкой") Все вышеописанные познания - результат убитых двух дней в гугле.

В общем, пожалуйста, помогите разобраться и реализовать эти идеи, буду очень признателен.

Вот ссылка на архив с сайтом: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18LaaYVzs7eJaS2vbMi21xlZ2FHkhKoGC - если у кого-то найдется время заглянуть в код или даже его поправить - будет просто офигительно!

UPD: решил добавить код

```html
<section class="engine"></section><section class="mbr-section mbr-section-hero mbr-section-full mbr-section-with-arrow mbr-parallax-background mbr-after-navbar" 
id="header1-3" data-rv-view="2" style="background-image: url(assets/images/intro.jpg);">

    <div class="mbr-overlay" style="opacity: 0.1; background-color: rgb(223, 0, 0);"></div>

    <div class="mbr-table-cell">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="mbr-section col-xs-0 col-xs-offset-0 text-xs-center">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="mbr-section col-xs-0 col-xs-offset-0 text-xs-center">

                    <img alt="Alice Goes To Motherland" src="assets/images/AGTM_string_white.png" width=60%>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mbr-arrow mbr-arrow-floating" aria-hidden="true"><a href="#gallery3-5"><i class="mbr-arrow-icon"></i></a></div>

</section>
```

Comment: @media queries в помощь.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже не первый раз прихожу к тому, что надо использовать это, но не могу найти нужный css, с которым работать((

Comment: Нашел) Но почему-то не работает использование background-image внутри css. акзалось бы, в описании стиля для общего случая указать одну картинку, а в группе @mdia (max-width:767px) - другую, при эом убрав из index.html вообще указание фоново картинки - и все должно заработать... но нет...(( что я делаю не так?((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, всем спасибо за отзывчивость, но решить проблему самостоятельно у меня так и не получилось. В итоге нашел через друзей веб-программиста, который за пять минут все пофиксил удаленно, за что ему огромное спасибо) Не знаю, можно ли здесь указывать контакты хороших людей, поэтому если кому надо - пишите мне, я поделюсь ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

```
background-size: 100vw;
```

или

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Картинка будет занимать 100% ширины окна (если она задана как фон div-а)

Вариант 2:

```
@media(max-width: <число>px){/*задаем размеры картинки*/}
```

Не забудьте подключить в header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: background-size пробовал и ранее, и сейчас еще раз - не помогает((

со вторым вариантом не понял - куда писать строку @media? (метатег в хедер добавил)

сейчас добавлю в пост скриншот участка кода

background-image относится к стилю section'a

Comment: @Юрий советую добавить фон к тегу body с со свойством background, указанным выше, скорее всего данный тег некорректно отображает изображение. По поводу media-запросов: они указываются в css. @media(...){ указываем тег/id/класс{свойство: значение;}...} Медиа-запрос применяет свойство при ширине экрана не большей/меньшей n

Comment: Слушайте, у меня прогресс) Картинка теперь в ширину вмещается полностью, но над ней и под ней остались висячие поля, как-будто на весь блок задано где-то, что он должен быть высотой во весь экран. Как это убрать? Как это задается обычно и как искать?

Comment: @Юрий попробуйте указать background-position: center top; или left top; Это может быть вызвано разрешением картинки. Также следует указать background-repeat: none; и цвет фона: если картика не сможет покрыть часть сайта, все не испортится. Можно через медиа-запрос указать другой фон с вертикальной ориентацией.